# The correct way to use multiple Viewholders in Listadapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I was following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding/) and tried to use multiple ViewHolders. An example use case would be a messaging app where the recyclerview has to display a sent message and a receiving message with different layouts. I got it working with the following solution:

```
class MyEntityDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyEntity>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyEntity, newItem: MyEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MyEntity, newItem: MyEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}

class MyAdapter :
    ListAdapter<MyEntity, MyAdapter.MyAbstractViewHolder>(
        MyEntityDiffCallback()
    ) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): MyAbstractViewHolder {
        if (viewType == 1){
            return MyViewHolder1.from(parent)
        }else{
            return MyViewHolder2.from(parent)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAbstractViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = getItem(position)
        if(item.someCounter > 5){
            return 1
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    abstract class MyAbstractViewHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        abstract fun bind(item: MyEntity)
    }

    class MyViewHolder2 private constructor(binding: Item2Binding) :
        MyAbstractViewHolder(binding) {

        override fun bind(
            item: MyEntity
        ) {
            val binding = binding as Item2Binding
            binding.message = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder2 {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding =
                    Item2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder2(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder1 private constructor(binding: Item1Binding) :
        MyAbstractViewHolder(binding) {

        override fun bind(
            item: MyEntity
        ) {
            val binding = binding as Item1Binding
            binding.message = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder1 {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding =
                    Item1Binding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder1(binding)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is this the way it should be implemented? I am not sure about the cast of the binding value in the bind method. Or are there other good practices to solve this with the Listadapter and the Databinding?

Comment: check this. I don't if it works or not. https://medium.com/@vivekvashistha/clean-way-to-implement-multi-views-in-recycler-view-using-listadapter-4c49afa0da1